# APK builds even when intentionally using an incorrect keystore password

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-keystore

I'm using Android Studio 3.3.2 to generate a signed apk. I've often built a signed apk using the correct credentials for keystore and key - but for some reason I tried to use a wrong keystore password intentionally.

The result: a fresh apk, perfectly signed, and not a single hint on a problem in the logs.

I generate signed apks via Android Studio/Generate signed APK dialog.

Is there something I'm missing?

Where's the "Cannot load key store: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect" dialog?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the opposite problem of getting the error you're looking for while having a perfectly valid keystore and providing its rightful password to gradle.

The problem seems that gradle keeps a cache and if you happen to change the keystore, he doesn't care at all.

Try to clean the tasks in Android studio or trash the entire `build` folder in your `app` and try again, that's how I fixed my own issue with the keystore.